# Getting Required license is missing: Runtime

Tags: configuration, azure, deployment

I am setting up Sitecore on Azure Web app PaaS.  I am using the official Sitecore packages to deploy a CD and CM role to azure.  These have been deployed as vanilla Sitecore instances with no additional changes, code or config from my application as of yet.  The packages are pre-configured by Sitecore to the azure setup, Redis azure search etc.

I am getting a `Required license is missing: Runtime` error when trying to load either the CD or CM role.  I have our organisational license file on the azure web app. I copied it onto the application using the Kudo debug console for now. The license has not expired.

I believe the correct license file location is being resolved because if I remove the file all together I get a `FATAL Could not find license file: D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\license.xml` error.  The minute I replace the license file I no longer get this error but still get the initial license missing error.  Any idea why this could be,  could it be an issue with uploading the file via the Kudu tools or possibly some missing section from the license file itself.  This file is used on other projects without issue and on local development.

Answer (score 1):

Check the file encoding. I heard someone mention at Symposium having issues with their license file in PaaS that was caused due to the way the license file had been uploaded mangling the text encoding so that Sitecore could not read it.

I believe the fix was to upload the license to the app service via FTPS using forced binary mode, or something similar.

Comment: Yes I think you could be correct,  I just deleted the file and created it again in Kudo manually and it was fine.